# Grid algorithm puzzle

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a grid of some width and height, where each cell can be of three possible values (presented as white, green and red in this illustration):

[image: illustration]
<sub>(source: [corexii.com](http://corexii.com/grid-algorithm-problem-2.png))</sub>

You may select any number of green cells (marked blue on the following illustration), which covers all red cells (marked yellow) in a *pre-determined* square radius (here **2**) around the selected cells:

[image: illustration]
<sub>(source: [corexii.com](http://corexii.com/grid-algorithm-problem-3.png))</sub>

The goal is to:

- Cover as many red cells as possible
- Using as few blue cells as possible
- Do it as fast as possible

Anyone have any ideas for an algorithm?

I'm looking at a lot of theory, but what I'm most interested in is an approximation to do this *quickly* rather than accurately. A fast, reasonable result is preferable to computing the optimal one all day.

*(The illustrations above may present the most normal distribution of these cells, but shouldn't be assumed to resemble all possible distributions.)*

Comment: your goal is very ambiguous. is there a priority order or a utility function?

Comment: Requirement #3 may be hard because it requires you to prove that no algorithm exists which is faster than the one you found.

Comment: I would work with the concept of the bounding rectangle: the smallest rectangular region which encompasses all of the red cells. I suspect that the solution will have the property that the covering squares stick within this bounding rectangle (provided that `n` is such that they fit within that rectangle). Straying outside of the rectangle doesn't achieve anything because there are no red cells there to cover; you're only diminishing the potential coverage of that square.

Comment: the problem can be transformed to solve the set cover problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem . note: this transformation doesn't help a bit, but I thought it's worth to mention it.

Comment: @Kaz: if you think about it, it's very easy to construct a counterexample

Comment: what's the typical value of `k`? can it be quite large?

Comment: what i think karoly is implying is that kaz's simplification doesn't take into account the fact that the distribution of green spaces may force the square area to be outside the bounding box (and if not, i wish you would just come out and say what you are thinking, karoly - isn't the idea to help people?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is a special case of the important NP-hard [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover). (The universe consists of the red cells, and each set consists of the red cells within the radius of one of the green cells.) The [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover#Greedy_algorithm) gets within a log *n* factor of the optimal result.

---

[templatetypedef is right to point out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796387/grid-algorithm-puzzle/9796460#comment12475589_9796460) that the fact that this problem is a special case of an NP-hard problem does not prove that it is in fact NP-hard too. That's why I was careful in my phrasing above not to imply the latter. But being a special case of an NP-hard problem is a signal that shouldn't be ignored: many special cases turn out on further investigation to be NP-hard themselves.

So here's a rough sketch that this problem is in fact NP-hard, by a reduction from VERTEX COVER FOR PLANAR GRAPHS OF DEGREE AT MOST FOUR.

Suppose we have a planar graph of degree at most four, for example:

[image: Four vertices connected a-b-c-d-a and a-d]

Represent each vertex by a green square, and each edge by an alternating chain of red and green squares such that there are an even number of green squares, an odd number of red squares, and each green square will only cover the two red squares on either side if chosen. With a radius of 2, this is one possible representation of the graph:

[image: representation of original graph in terms of the covering problem]

In order to cover all the red squares, we need to choose at least half of the green squares on each chain corresponding to an edge the original graph. If we choose exactly half of the green squares on each chain, that leaves an uncovered red square at one end of each edge (and we can choose which end). So we get the minimum set of green squares if we can find the minimum set of vertices such that every edge is incident to a vertex in that set.

In the example, we can cover the red squares using eight green squares if we pick vertices **a** and **d**:

[image: minimum cover with eight green squares selected and coloured blue]

And this corresponds to the minimum vertex cover in the original graph:

[image: minimum vertex cover]

Comment: meets the 1st & 3rd criteria, fails on the 2nd one

Comment: The fact that this is a special case of set covering does not mean that it's necessarily computationally difficult to solve.  For example, 2SAT is a special case of SAT, but has a linear-time solution.

Comment: yeah, if the radius can be infinite then you only need to add one blue square. If the radius is small then it is also easy to compute.

Comment: I can use an adapted version of this. I'll minimize the number of covering sets with heuristics (basically, just stop when the next best set isn't worth it anymore).

Comment: @templatetypedef: see the revised answer.

Comment: @Karoly: when a problem is NP-hard, finding the optimal solution takes exponential time (as far as we know), so something has to give: often the best you can do is to look for an approximate solution in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Gareth Rees: of course, but when I wrote that comment you haven't even responded to templatetypedef.